# Silverlight 4.0 in Visual Studio 2008?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I've been trying to find official requirements for Silverlight 4.0, but can't seem to find anything.

What I want to know is if VS2008 supports Silverlight 4.0, or if I need to upgrade to VS2010.

The only mention I could find was on this Silverlight forum:
http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/156538/350841.aspx

Does anyone know of an official link?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I pretty sure you require Visual Studio 2010 to use Silverlight 4.  I was using 3 and had to install VS2010 to use Silverlight 4.  There are no SL4 tools in VS2008.

Notice no mention of VS2008: http://www.silverlight.net/getstarted/

Link to tools also with no mention or links to alternate downloads:
http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=68A158AF-9BB8-4855-A724-D09D196EAAF3&displaylang=en

On the Silverlight forums asking to build SL4 in VS2008:
http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/t/150762.aspx

Also, Microsoft I am sure wants to provide as many reasons as possible to get developers to upgrade to VS2010.  Silverlight 4 is one of them.

Comment: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=68A158AF-9BB8-4855-A724-D09D196EAAF3&displaylang=en not found

Answer (score 0):

You can't use Silverlight 4 with Visual Studio 2008.

[Silverlight.net](http://www.silverlight.net/getstarted/) only mentions Visual Studio 2010

As does the [Silverlight page](http://www.microsoft.com/silverlight/) on microsoft.com.

Answer (score 0):

Due to the fact that there was no support for SL4 in VS2008 whilst it was in beta, I don't think it will ever be available.